# Appharbor + Bitbucket is not triggering any ideas?

Tags: build, bitbucket, appharbor

I have configured AppHarbor and BitBucket, and it worked one time then it just stopped.

The time it worked I had some tests that failed so it did not build. Once I fixed the tests and committed everything I was expecting it would trigger again but it never did.
I attempted this http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/trigger-builds-with-git
but it did not work as well.

Any ideas or suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the `apphb` user as a collaborator on Bitbucket? You might also want to check that you only copied the token part of the url into the Bitbucket verification token box (and not the entire url).

Comment: Perfect, I had the user, but I don't know why I had the whole url on the config. As soon as I changed it triggered correctly.

Comment: At one point you where supposed to use the whole URL. I got bit by this also.